# jquery Ajax post forbidden

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, post

I've a problem with a simple ajax post by jquery:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "ucUploadDownloadCommand.ascx/UploadXLSFile",
  data: "{}",
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: function (response) {
       $(".im").css('visibility', 'hidden');
  },
  error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
          alert(xhr.statusText);
          alert(textStatus);
          alert(error);
  }
```

and in code behind (file `ucUploadDownloadCommand.ascx.vb`):

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Sub UploadXLSFile()
        Dim a As New StringBuilder()
        ...
    End Sub
```

but it goes wrong with

> "Forbidden" error (no "not found" one)

. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to call a web method inside a user control. You will need to move your method definition directly to page. And as far as I remember web method need to be static in order to work.